# Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have been trying to publish my asp.net core 2.2 app to azure and all I get is this error:

`Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore'`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ClientNotifications" Version="1.17.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sendgrid" Version="9.11.0" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\lib\material-kit\font-awesome\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\lib\popper\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\lib\toastr\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

`
The above is my csproj file.

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyS3W.png)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following line. You don't need it.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
```

Comment: if you check the code snippet above.. you'll see that that package reference exists